# Modify JSON string

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Say if I have a object:

`{ "name": "abc", "profession": null, "createdOn": "2022-01-05 10:00:05" }`,

when I convert it to a string, I need output like:

`'{"name">"abc", "profession">nil, "createdOn">"2022-01-05 10:00:05" }`

If I global replace like:

`JSON.stringify(inputObject).replace(/null/g, 'nil').replace(/:/g, '>')`,

I will get:

`{"name">"abc", "profession">nil, "createdOn">"2022-01-05 10>00>05" }`

There are couple of problems here:

1. It replaces all the instances of `:`, whereas I need to replace the ones in front of key names only (like key`:`value)
2. Though replacement of `null` to `nil` is working, if `profession` was `"profession": "null blah"`, it would make it `"profession">"nil blah"`. I don't want to modify if the value is not `null`.

Is there a better way to handle above scenarios?

Comment: One way is to use Object.keys and to interate through each property. And you can keep a string variable where you push everything you want

Comment: It is rarely a good idea to modify valid JSON into invalid JSON. Why do you need this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution may be:

```js
const a = {
  name: 'abc',
  gender: 'null',
  gender2: 'my null value',
  profession: null,
  createdOn: '2022-01-05 10:00:05',
};

const b = JSON.stringify(a)
  .replace(/":/g, '">')
  .replace(/">null/g, '">nil')
;


console.log(b);
```

Output:

```
{"name">"abc","gender">"null","gender2">"my null value","profession>nil,"createdOn
">"2022-01-05 10:00:05"}
```

Comment: I fixed for nil too. I just missed `"`. `.replace(/">null/g, '">nil')`

Answer (score 1):

```js
function format(inputObject) {
  if (inputObject) {
    if (typeof inputObject === "object" && !Array.isArray(inputObject)) {
      const objectEntries = Object.entries(inputObject);
      if (objectEntries.length) {
        const reformatted =
          objectEntries
            .map(([key, value]) => `"${key}">${!value ? 'nil' : "\"" + value + "\""}`)
            .join(",") || "";
        return `{${reformatted}}`;
      }
      return "{}";
    }
  }
  return `${inputObject}`;
}
```

---

### ***Illustration***

```js
const obj = {
  "name": "abc",
  "profession": null,
  "createdOn": "2022-01-05 10:00:05"
};

function format(inputObject) {
  if (inputObject) {
    if (typeof inputObject === "object" && !Array.isArray(inputObject)) {
      const objectEntries = Object.entries(inputObject);
      if (objectEntries.length) {
        const reformatted =
          objectEntries
          .map(([key, value]) => `"${key}">${!value ? 'nil' : "\"" + value + "\""}`)
          .join(",") || "";
        return `{${reformatted}}`;
      }
      return "{}";
    }
  }
  return `${inputObject}`;
}

console.log(format(obj));
```

---

### ***`WYSIWYG`*** => ***`WHAT YOU SHOW IS WHAT YOU GET`***